# ¿Cómo tener TAB-VIDEOS en mi KINGTUBE theme?

Tags: video

Tengo una web tube, con el tema KINGTUBE de WP-SCRIPT. Y ellos solo me dejan poner un vídeo, como seria lo común.

Pero que tal si quieres poner mas opciones de servidores de vídeos, tipo esta pagina: https://dragonball.sullca.com/capitulos/dragon-ball/8

En donde puede seleccionar diferentes servidores para sus vídeos.

¿Puedo hacer esto editando el siguiente código que tengo para mis posts en mi tema?:

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'video' );

endwhile; // End of the loop.
?>

</main><!-- #main -->
```

O hay un plugin? Porque yo ya tengo una estructura dada, y siento eso DIFICULTA TODO.